# Should we stop using aluminium foil in food preparation and storage?

Tags: food-safety, alzheimers

In view of the findings reported in [strong-evidence-linking-aluminium-alzheimers][2] should we stop using aluminium containers to store food and aluminium foil to wrap food? I am 85 years old, is it going to make any difference to me now?

---

Thanks for the comments. I though the link above would be sufficient, but the original source appears to be [this one](http://www.hippocraticpost.com/mental-health/strong-evidence-linking-aluminium-alzheimers/)  which reports a high concentration of aluminium in the brain tissue of sufferers.

My own view is that this is not enough evidence of a causal link between the disease and the use of aluminium foil in contact with food, so I am not going to stop using it. It could be for instance that these individuals have a higher propensity to concentrate aluminium in this way, as is suggested in the end of the discussion in the second article referred to above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The association between aluminum and Alzheimer's disease has been evident for many years. At one point, there was even a discussion that the aluminum in our deodorant was causing an epidemic in Alzheimer's (see this article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2319278).

Truly, there is something to be said about exposure to high quantities of any metal and having adverse effects in the body. However, given the trace concentrations in our deodorant, and the fact that we aren't eating the aluminum foil with our cheeseburger, it is extremely unlikely to lead to any adverse effects in most people (see this article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1296988).

Further, at the age of 85, you are at higher risk of Alzheimer's than if you were 55 or 65. It tends to be later in onset (https://www.alzheimers.org.uk/site/scripts/documents_info.php?documentID=102). Alzheimer's should not be mixed up with age-related dementia is an entirely separate discussion (http://www.alz.org/what-is-dementia.asp).

Comment: You need to provide sources for your assertions of fact.

Comment: You can review this classic article about aluminum and deodorants: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2319278

Comment: This one talks about the lack of toxicity associated with aluminum foil: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1296988

Comment: Edit your question and add them. Comments have a way of vanishing or being ignored.

Comment: Quote from the first article cited: "These results are provocative but inconclusive due to methodologic problems relating to the necessary use of surrogate respondents and the long time period of potential exposure for this dementing disease." This is not what I would call "evident".